# Каким способом лучше верстать плиточные сайты

Tags: html, css

Нужно сверстать плиточный сайт, чтобы блоки перемещались, на больших экранах вставали почти все в линию, на  средних часть блоков смещались в низ, а на меленьких поочередно шли.
 
Какие технологии и способы лучше всего использовать?

Comment: глобально - сетки фреймворков а-ля Bootstrapб Skeleton. а если кокретно какой-то родитель так должен cебя вести, то используйте т.н. технологию flexbox (`display: flex`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
          flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
body .block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

---

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

---

FlexBox Grid [flexboxgrid.com](http://flexboxgrid.com/)

Responsive Grid with Flexbox [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/irinakramer/pen/jcLlp)

Comment: Блоки одинакового размера - так не интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Сам не пользовался, но думаю, должны подойти [Grid Style Sheets](https://gridstylesheets.org/).

А вообще, скоро сделают поддержку [css grid'ов](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

Из js-библиотек могу назвать [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).